# Node exporter: Server resource & Disk space stopped showing data

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

Grafana and Node Exporter Version details are as follows,

```
Grafana - v8.1.4 (6855cdff7c)
Node Exporter - v1.0.1.linux-amd64
```

**Problem:** On grafana for `1 Node Exporter for Prometheus Dashboard EN v20201010` dashboard suddenly not showing data for `Server resource overview` and `Disk Space used Basic` sections. Refer to the below screenshot.

[image: Node Exporter Dashboard]

It was working till last week, there is no change on Prometheus and Grafana's side. Node exporter service is running fine in all the servers and I can see the metrics from the `http://server-1:9100/metrics` link. this looks like Prometheus scraping data correctly.

What could be the problem? Some pointers to solve this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the system's time. Have noticed that server's time was not in sync with our domain server.Therefore fixed by running `ntpdate -s domain-server`, Now able to view the metrics on Grafana Dashboard.